# Underlining first letter of Label C++ (Underline doesn't show)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc

**Problem:**
I wish to underline the first letter of certain static text controls (such as Login and Password).  The letters become underlined when the `ALT` key is pressed.

**What I have tried:**
In C#, I was able to acheive this by using an ampersand.  Such as "&Log in" or "&Password".  I am trying to find a similar method in C++.  The below picture shows an example in C#:

[image: Example]

*I am using MFC/C++ in Visual Studio 2010.*

**Edit:**
Added information about the `ALT` key.  Here is an example of what I am trying in Visual Studio 2010's properties box.  I am adding an ampersand to the front of the "Caption"'s text.

[image: example 2]

When I run my program in the debugger, the first letter is not underlined (until `ALT` is pressed):
[image]

Comment: You do it the same way (ampersand before the letter you want underlined).

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Then you probably need to "show your work", so to speak--it definitely *can* work, so if it's not working for you, you're apparently doing it incorrectly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I took a snip of what I am trying.  Thanks for trying to help...

Comment: Try hitting the `Alt` key and see if they appear: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: When I hit the Alt key, the first letters **do**  appear underlined.  I am researching a way to persistently show the underlined letters for all users and will post a response in a few minutes. Thanks.  @MarkRansom

Comment: This is entirely normal, your machine has the "Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key" option turned on.  Seems that you prefer it to work that way :)  Avoid forcing your preferences on the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After help from the SO community, it seems that using the ampersand (&) symbol before the desired underlined letter is the correct way.  There was a setting on my personal machine that would keep the underlined letters hidden until the `ALT` key was pressed.

According to the MSDN:

> A user often has to press ALT in order to see access key designations. To ensure that you address them throughout the development process, set your computer to persistently display access keys.
>   [image]

**In Windows 8:** Open Control Panel -> Ease of Access Center -> Make the Keyboard easier to use.

At the bottom of the screen, check "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys".

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental difference between a menu and a static control.

To do this in a menu, you do it just like in C#. Here's a screen shot of editing a menu in a C++ project:

[image]

...and here's the result:

[image]

For a static control, you have to clear the `SS_NOPREFIX` style for the control to get the same behavior. However, it's been my observation that under some circumstances the underline doesn't show (but I haven't ever pinned down the precise circumstances under which the underline didn't show--I *think* when it happened, I fixed it by changing the font, but I don't remember for sure).

Comment: The SS_NOPREFIX (No Prefix) is defaulted to false in Visual Studio's properties box.  This is not an answer to my problem, but may be for someone else. Thanks.